# Can a pointer point to another pointer instead of a label in DNS compression?

Tags: networking, dns, compression

Should DNS clients be worried about the DNS message compression in which pointers may point to another pointer instead of label name? Although doing so seems to be unambiguous, there is not talk about it in the rfc I am referring to.

From the DNS rfc1035:

> The compression scheme allows a domain name in a message to be
>   represented as either:
>
> - a sequence of labels ending in a zero octet
> - a pointer
> - a sequence of labels ending with a pointer

Can DNS clients expect such behaviour in the server response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, it can.**

I haven't found anything in any of the relevant DNS standard disallowing this, so you need to be able to decode this case if you happen to receive one. The definition of message compression in [RFC 1035 4.1.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035) says:

> In this scheme, an entire domain name or a list of labels at the end of a domain name is replaced with a pointer to a prior occurance of the same name.

There's nothing here saying that such an occurence would have to be a literal list of labels. Given that the "bare pointer" is just a special case of "list of labels ending with a pointer", decoding it shouldn't require any extra complexity.

Pointers to pointers are rare in the wild because there's no real reason to generate them and they would complicate encoding. But they seem to be perfectly valid as far as the spec is concerned.

Comment: Specifications say "is replaced with a pointer to a prior occurance
of the same name." so a pointer should point to a name not another pointer I think. But a DNS client has to be robust and can use any kind of mess from other servers so it needs to be vigilant and handle all soft of strange cases.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek But a "name" is not equal to "list of labels" (which is what you seem to mean when you say "point to a name"). A "list of labels" is one of the three possible representations of a "name", the other two options being "pointer" and a combination of the two. See the quote in the question above.

Comment: My understanding of the phrase I quote is that the destination is a name, as in a list of labels. Otherwise I guess the phrase would have been different. And I know fully well what RFC 1034 and 1035 says, I read them almost daily...

Comment: If you allow a pointer to a pointer you open things as loops...

Comment: See https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-dns/issues/127 ; it seems some software allow it (understand how to parse it), but it seems clearly to fall in the "not in the specification" bucket. Yet it can happen in the wild, yes.

Comment: On a meta level "I haven't found anything in any of the relevant DNS standard disallowing this" is a dangerous argument. Specifications do not focus on listing everything that is not allowed, they tend to focus on things that are allowed implying that everything else, without doing a list, IS disallowed. Then you have two views, either Postel side as in "be liberal in what you accept" (or at least defend yourself properly) or be more strict because Postel law is fine but at least in security is counter productive and there everything not specified as possible should be clearty impossible.

Answer (score 1):

No (in theory, but everything can happen in practice)

Surprisingly, I think the answer is in another RFC:

[RFC 2929: Domain Name System (DNS) IANA Considerations](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2929)

whose section 3.3 says this:

> At the present time, there are two categories of label types, data
> labels and compression labels.  Compression labels are pointers to
> data labels elsewhere within an RR or DNS message and are intended to
> shorten the wire encoding of NAMEs.

Note in particular that it says that compression labels are pointers to data labels. It does not say that compression labels can be pointers to other compression labels, so out of this it feels to me the case of a pointer to a pointer is not in the specification.

As discussed in comments, the specifications do not say this case is forbidden, but they do not either list all other possible forbidden things. They tell what is allowed and everything else should not be allowed. Hence, I disagree with @TooTea answer using argument "it is not explicitly forbidden in the specification, hence it is allowed" and the conclusion coming from it.

Based on that, I conclude that pointer should not point to another pointer if you want to claim to be following the DNS specification, but at the same time if you have to handle any unknown incoming message you have to defend yourself against things like that and others (like forward pointers, etc.), and then decide if you want to accept it or just refuse it.

Postel's law might make you think it is better to accept it, but I believe it is better to just drop this kind of message and not try to accommodate it, because:

- as said above, that case is not in the specification, so "shouldn't happen"
- I do hope that this case is rare in the wild (but I have no proof either way); for the reason of the next point
- if it happens it may be a sign of a bad compression algorithm on the side of the sender, so no need to try to compensate for that buggy software.

Because if you have X pointing to Y which points to Z, why not have X point to Z anyway directly? Having an "intermediate" pointer does not provide any additional feature, and hence has no reason to exist (besides bugs and invalid implementations).